# Sending DataStream in Flink using sockets; serialization issue

Tags: serialization, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I want to send Stream of data from VM to host machine and I am using method `writeToSocket()` as shown below:

```
joinedStreamEventDataStream.writeToSocket("192.168.1.10", 6998) ;
```

Here `joinedStreamEventDataStream` is of type `DataStream<Integer,Integer>`.

Can someone please tell me how should I pass serializer to above method.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

It depends a little bit on how you would like to read the data from the socket. If you expect it to be the String representation of the data, then you could do it via:

```java
joinedStreamEventDataStream.map(new MapFunction<Type, String>() {
    @Override
    public String map(Type value) throws Exception {
        return value.toString();
    }
}).writeToSocket(hostname, port, new SimpleStringSchema());
```

If you want to keep Flink's serialization format, then you can do write:

```java
joinedStreamEventDataStream.writeToSocket(
    hostname, 
    port, 
    new TypeInformationSerializationSchema<>(
        joinedStreamEventDataStream.getType(), 
        env.getConfig()));
```

If you want to output it in your own serialization format, then you have to implement your own `SerializationSchema` as pointed out by Alex.

Answer (score 1):

The `writeToSocket()` method takes 3 arguments: a socket host and port and also an implementation of `SerializationSchema` interface which used to serialize your data. So your implementation maybe like this:

```
joinedStreamEventDataStream.writeToSocket(
    "192.168.1.10",  // host name
    6998,  // port
    new SerializationSchema<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public byte[] serialize(Integer element) {
            return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(element).array();
        }
    }
);
```

It's true if `joinedStreamEventDataStream` has `DataStream<Integer>` type.